# Long delays when laptop cannot access domain controller

Tags: windows-8.1, domain, windows-domain, timeout

I have a laptop that is part of a domain.

Unfortunately, when the laptop is not connected to the domain, I observe extremely irritating delays in various situations. For example, when I start Google Chrome and then exit it, the process doesn't actually terminate until approximately 85 seconds after the window has been closed. I can confirm this is caused by the lack of a reachable domain controller, because Process Monitor shows me that (in this case) Google Chrome is attempting a TCP Reconnect operation to the domain controller on port `epmap` and failing. And furthermore, when I connect to the domain via VPN, the delays go away entirely.

Is there any way for me to fix this issue? The delays are irritating enough that I can't use my laptop unless I'm actually connected to the domain, which is not something I would expect.

Comment: Is your laptop setup to use a proxy?

Comment: @CharlesH: Nope!

Comment: It says to me something to do with Microsoft DCE Service. Normally epmap is called locally from Port 135 for DHCP, DNS, WINS, etc. I'm guessing your network adapter IPv4 is set to DHCP and using your router as its DHCP?

Comment: @CharlesH: I believe so. I guess what I need to know first is, is the behavior I'm seeing normal? There's not much point trying to identify the cause if it's a well-known issue. But if you don't experience the same thing when you disconnect from your domain then it becomes a lot more interesting.

Comment: In my opinion its 100% not standard behavior. I've rolled out thousands of domain laptops in my time and never had any complaints of this nature. I'm wondering if your IT department have got some form of monitoring software or SCCM that is trying to constantly talk back to the DC... It's really odd..

Comment: @CharlesH: Interesting, good to know. I doubt there's anything weird on my laptop like that but I guess I really don't know for sure. I feel like it might be a group policy refreshing issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you place some more details on your network setup, export of ipconfig /all maybe? see if I can assist from there...

Comment: Also Route Print from command line would be helpful... if you unsure how to perform these commands please let me know and ill assist

Comment: @CharlesH: Thanks I got it, here you go! (I anonymized the data.) [IPConfig](http://pastebin.com/pWmiefgP) [RoutePrint](http://pastebin.com/3xS0fUVB)

Comment: hmm nothing out of the ordinary there... sorry bit of a mystery to me not sure what is going on...